# Is it correct to call a scientific project worked on during a vacation "Volunteer scientific work"?

Tags: phrases

During my vacation I worked on a scientific project. Since I would like to put it on my resume, I have added the following:

> 1- Volunteer scientific work: Implementation of salient Region Detector

Is it correct to say the project is a "Volunteer scientific work"? I want to say that I developed it myself during my vacation.

Comment: You say "I developed it myself", which implies not only that you *worked* on it independently, but also that *it was your idea in the first place* (and perhaps no-one else knows or cares what you worked on). People often spend time dabbling in "personal projects" of little or no value to anyone else, simply because they find them "interesting". But "volunteer work" usually implies you contributed your (unpaid) efforts to some larger project involving many other people - in which context it's far more likely the project was fully organised to address a genuine real-world need. Which is yours?

Comment: It’s a resume, so the first question to ask yourself is whether anyone will care. This isn’t to denigrate your work or your feelings about it, but the only purpose of a resume is to gain you the next step in a dialog. This looks like something for the “hobbies and interests” section that helps the reader visualize you better as a person.  In that part of a resume you have some freedom to abbreviate your phrases, and you can avoid the term volunteer completely.

Comment: "Volunteer scientific work" is understandable, though "voluntary…" might be better. However, what does "Implementation of salient Region Detector" mean in your scientific speciality or in your own language, please? In English it seems to me obvious that could only work in a very specialised community

Comment: If you want to show the value of this work, you could highlight what you had to do to achieve it; eg. learn a new programming language, understanding the technology of "salient region detectors"  (whatever they are), develop a novel algorithm ...

Comment: [what the preferable wording **s**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with LetsamrIt that "volunteer work" is not the right term. If your research was later taken up or recognized by a school or company or if it was published in a reputable publication, by all means, list in on your resume. If none of these was true, I'm not sure what to advise on whether or not to list your activity, nor how you should list it.

Answer (score 0):

Review if it is 'scientific project' or 'science project'.

2) Under the heading "Projects undertaken" usually seen in resume, you may simply say, "Developed and implemented Salient Region Detector"